# How do I wrap a content type with certain tags in Drupal 8?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, drupal-8

I'm relatively new to Drupal 8 and I want to do something very simple, but since Drupal isn't the most intuitive CMS in the world, I'm hitting a snag on how to do this.

I'm using Drupal 8 with the Bootstrap Theme. I've got a few different content types (Generic Page, Blog, etc).

What I want to do is wrap *JUST* the Blog content type in a couple of div tags around the main content. **JUST the blog content type.** That's it. I've dug around in the content type settings and can't find anything that'll allow me to do this.

I really don't want to have to manually add these tags every time a blog is posted.

I'm a *little* familiar with the twig template system in Drupal 8, but would need a bit of handholding to navigate this.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sources:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!node.html.twig/8.2.x

Basically you can create a new template in your theme called node--blog.html.twig(as stated in first link) and in it put the code from second link (click View source) and add whatever html you need there, the part with {{ content }} in your content, you can wrap it.

However if your tags are in node you can refer to them as {{content.tags}} and then hide them from main content using  {{ content|without('tags') }}

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a try!